# Chrome is blocking all unsecure https sites without asking me

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, firefox

Some websites provide https connection and they don't have proper certificates, so Chrome is blocking them. Firefox warns me and asks what to do, but Chrome blocks the site and doesn't even ask me if I want to visit it.

This is a screenshot:

[image]

How can I disable this so Chrome doesn't block any site for any reason?

Comment: Just install the certificate into the certificate store on the OS.  You can also type `BADIDEA` into chrome

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of cases, you can open the details and then choose to 'continue to this site' anyway. Of course, you'll be browsing insecure then and won't know if someone is attempting any man-in-the-middle attack or just watching.

If a site has enabled HSTS, you will be unable to view it without a valid SSL certificate and secure connection. If this is the case, you will need to wait until the site operator fixes their config so that it is compatible with your system.

The specific error that you're getting `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` is caused by an incompatible SSL configuration on the server end. This means that they're using an old SSL implementation or cipher suite.

[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/errsslversionorciphermismatch/567fd181-7a27-48c5-95d1-b3095df255ec?auth=1)

Comment: "continue to this site" button is not appairing :(

Comment: @FarhanSajid That means that the SSL configuration on your computer is incompatible with the server. Have you changed any security settings before this issue started showing up?